# ffmpeg convert multiple files from avi dv video (dvsd) to avi h.264 + mp3(mp4)

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a bunch of avi files inside a folder (on Windows 7) with Codec DV Video (dvds). These are copied directly from my Sony DCR-PC120E Pal camera with the included software from Sony.

The problem is that the old video files get so big when they are copied to the harddrive. So I've used the VLC Convert/Save function wich reduced the size of the videos to 1/10 of the filesize without noticing any big signal loss. Another problem is that with VLC I have to convert one file at a time, and I have probably over 100 files.

I'v configured ffmpeg to work on my Windows 7 pc but can't find a batch script that converts multiple files from avi dv video (dvsd) to avi h.264 + mp3(mp4).

Any help is greatly apreciated.

Comment: I've got a batch script that will work for you. I'll post it when I get home in a couple hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code (save as `convertall.bat`).  I've tested it with the newest version of the ffmpeg.exe binary installed from the [Zeranoe daily builds](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) on Windows 7.  Adjust the `-q:a` and `crf` values to your [video](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MPEG-4) and [audio](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3) quality/size preference.

```
echo off
echo *
echo **********************************************
echo *                                            *
echo *  USE TO BATCH CONVERT ALL AVIS IN FOLDER   *
echo *                                            *
echo *   1) place videos in a folder              *
echo *   2) copy convertall.bat to your folder    *
echo *   3) double click convertall.bat           *
echo *                                            *
echo *                                            *
echo **********************************************


FOR /f "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /b *.AVI') DO (
ffmpeg.exe -i "%%G" -y -c:v libx264  -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 -crf 22 -pix_fmt yuv420p "%%~nG".mp4
)

echo                  ************
echo        ********                **********
echo      ********                    **********
echo    ****** DONE WITH BATCH CONVERTING ********
echo      ********                    **********
echo        ********                **********
echo                  ************
pause
```

Comment: For `libx264`,  `-qscale is ignored, -crf is recommended`. CRF values between 18 and 28 are recommended.

Comment: Amazing.
This really saves me alot of time. Thank you very much:)

Comment: No problem. Please accept as the correct answer if you found this useful.

Comment: @user2427836 just click the checkmark next to my answer. Thanks

Comment: I keep getting these error messages when I run the script. Concealing bitstream errors timesLast message repeated 4 times. I also notice that with long videos audio and video gets out of sync. Is there a way to correct this so video and audio is keept in sync?

Comment: Also is there a way to speed up coding? The videos I import are from 2002 and earlier so I don't have to code for 4k ultra hd quality.

Comment: @user2427836 Make sure you're using an up to date `ffmpeg` ([Windows downloads](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)). [Use a faster preset](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#a2.Chooseapreset), such as `-preset fast`. Also, MP3 audio in MP4 container can be problematic for some players: change `-c:a libmp3lame -q:a 2` to `-c:a aac` to encode AAC audio instead which is far more common in MP4.